# React native how to manually change API level to 26

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been building my apps using Expo v27.0.0 which is react-native v0.55 (latest version as I know of at the time writing this post), and apparently when building the app, the target API is 25 and google play require the app to target at least API 26 to be published.

I have tried to detach the app from expo and rebuild using android studio after change the targetSDKVersion, however I keep getting too many errors with the gradle, and as I know, I won't be able to go back to react native if I detach, so I would prefer not to detach.

Is there any way to manually change the API level in react native ?
All answers are greatly welcomed.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you ever find a viable solution? It's really annoying, and React-Native 56 is really not ready

Comment: update to latest react native and expo, they now support the target API 26